# How can I validate a string only contains specific alpha characters in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to determine if an input string contains only the characters G, C, T or A.  The string I am provided can contain any amount of those characters, in any order.  If the string contains any characters other than those specified, I should return "".

I've seen several solutions where I can validate that a string only contains numbers or letters but how can I validate that a string only contains specific alpha characters before I execute a block of code?

Example:

- Input_1 = "C"
- Result_1 = runs code block
- Input_2 = "ACGTXXXCTTAA"
- Result_2 = does not run code block

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). What have you tried? I don't know ruby, but since it is not considered an esoteric language, this should be straightforward *as heck* if you have any clue what you're doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## With regex

```
input = "ACGTCTTAA"
if  input =~ /\A[GCTA]+\z/
  # put your code here
end
```

It means any `succession of 'G', 'C', 'T' or 'A's from the beginning to the end of the string`.

If an empty string is acceptable, you could use `/\A[GCTA]*\z/` instead.

## With String#delete

You could also delete every 'G', 'C', 'T' and 'A's with [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-delete), and check if the string becomes empty :

```
"C".delete("GCTA").empty? #=> true
"ACGTXXXCTTAA".delete("GCTA").empty? #=> false
"ACGTCTTAA".delete("GCTA").empty? #=> true
"".delete("GCTA").empty? #=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to check - something like

```
puts 'run code' if 'C' =~ /^[GCTA]+$/
```

where:

```
^  = start of line 
$  = end of line
[] = match any character within 
+  = one or more of previous
```

Comment: Edited answer to allow for multiple characters

Comment: This returns `nil` when there is no match, which may be a good idea even though the OP asked that an empty string be returned when there's no match.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the solution you're looking for.

```
"C".match(/^[GCTA]+$/) => #<MatchData "C">
"ACGTXXXCTTAA".match(/^[GCTA]+$/) => nil
```

Comment: What about "ACGTXXX\nCTTAA"?

Comment: Then it's better to use
    "ACGTXXX\nCTTAA".match(/\A[GCTA]+\z/)

Answer (score 0):

Non-regexp answer:

```
nucleic_acid_sequence = ['G','C','T','A']

test_input = 'GFWG'

unless (test_input.chars-nucleic_acid_sequence).any?
  puts 'valid input!'
end
```